# Run batch with C++

Tags: c++, string, batch-file, char, concatenation

I am a C++ beginner but I am trying to make a program that takes command line arguments and executes a bat file with those same arguments.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argsc, char *args[]) {
    if (argsc!=0) {
        char arg[] = "run.bat ",args;
        return system(arg);
    }
    return argsc;
}
```

Here is my question:

How do I concatenate "run.bat " with args? System will only take "const char*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 string cmd = "run.bat";
 for(int i = 1; i < argsc; i++)
 {
    cmd += " ";
    cmd += args[i]
 }
 return system(cmd.c_str());
```

(Of course, args that have spaces in them will need to be processed further, by adding quotes, and arguments with quotes may need escaping, and lots of other complications in cases where `args` contains stuff that isn't straight forward to deal with)

Comment: Space added, as well as a comment about spaced/quotes/escaping.